# Getting Null Pointer Exception when mapping SQL Server Database to MySQL Database with MapReduce

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am new to Cloud Data Fusion and am trying to map tables in a SQL Server Database to a MySQL Database.
I have already faced many issues which I managed to solve namely:

- Fixed permissions for the service account so it could access all the resources it required;
- Added IP to the allowed connections in my SQL Server;
- Am using system.profile.properties.dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable = false to prevent SSL bug issue as reported in another question.

After this last fix, I am now trying to deal with a NULL pointer exception on the MapReduce job at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.ProgramControllerServiceAdapter#97-MapReduceRunner-phase-1.

The stacktrace provided by Data Fusion is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at io.cdap.plugin.db.batch.source.AbstractDBSource.loadSchemaFromDB(AbstractDBSource.java:138) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.db.batch.source.AbstractDBSource.loadSchemaFromDB(AbstractDBSource.java:155) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.db.batch.source.AbstractDBSource.prepareRun(AbstractDBSource.java:241) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.db.batch.source.AbstractDBSource.prepareRun(AbstractDBSource.java:68) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.lambda$prepareRun$0(WrappedBatchSource.java:51) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.Caller$1.call(Caller.java:30) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.StageLoggingCaller.call(StageLoggingCaller.java:40) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSource.java:50) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSource.java:36) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.submit.SubmitterPlugin.lambda$prepareRun$2(SubmitterPlugin.java:71) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext$2.run(AbstractContext.java:551) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.data2.transaction.Transactions$CacheBasedTransactional.finishExecute(Transactions.java:224) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.data2.transaction.Transactions$CacheBasedTransactional.execute(Transactions.java:211) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:546) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:534) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.submit.SubmitterPlugin.prepareRun(SubmitterPlugin.java:69) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.PipelinePhasePreparer.prepare(PipelinePhasePreparer.java:111) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.mapreduce.MapReducePreparer.prepare(MapReducePreparer.java:97) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.mapreduce.ETLMapReduce.initialize(ETLMapReduce.java:192) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.api.mapreduce.AbstractMapReduce.initialize(AbstractMapReduce.java:109) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.api.mapreduce.AbstractMapReduce.initialize(AbstractMapReduce.java:32) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService$1.initialize(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:182) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService$1.initialize(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:177) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.lambda$initializeProgram$1(AbstractContext.java:640) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:600) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.initializeProgram(AbstractContext.java:637) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService.beforeSubmit(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:547) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService.startUp(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:226) ~[na:na]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$1.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:47) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService$2$1.run(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:450) [na:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S.:
After solving this issue, I am now running into this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.cdap.plugin.db.DBRecord cannot be cast to io.cdap.plugin.db.DBRecord
at io.cdap.plugin.db.batch.source.AbstractDBSource.transform(AbstractDBSource.java:267) ~[database-commons-1.2.0.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.lambda$transform$2(WrappedBatchSource.java:69) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.Caller$1.call(Caller.java:30) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.StageLoggingCaller.call(StageLoggingCaller.java:40) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.transform(WrappedBatchSource.java:68) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.transform(WrappedBatchSource.java:36) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.TrackedTransform.transform(TrackedTransform.java:74) ~[cdap-etl-core-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.UnwrapPipeStage.consumeInput(UnwrapPipeStage.java:44) ~[cdap-etl-batch-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.UnwrapPipeStage.consumeInput(UnwrapPipeStage.java:32) ~[cdap-etl-batch-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.PipeStage.consume(PipeStage.java:44) ~[cdap-etl-batch-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.PipeTransformExecutor.runOneIteration(PipeTransformExecutor.java:43) ~[cdap-etl-batch-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.mapreduce.TransformRunner.transform(TransformRunner.java:142) ~[cdap-etl-batch-6.0.1.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.mapreduce.ETLMapReduce$ETLMapper.map(ETLMapReduce.java:230) ~[cdap-etl-batch-6.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146) [hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.5.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapperWrapper.run(MapperWrapper.java:135) [na:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787) [hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) [hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175) [hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.8.5.jar:na]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_212]
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) [na:1.8.0_212]
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844) [hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169) [hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.8.5.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.distributed.MapReduceContainerLauncher.launch(MapReduceContainerLauncher.java:114) [io.cdap.cdap.cdap-app-fabric-6.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(Unknown Source) [hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.8.5.jar:na]
```

P.S. 2:
After solving the aforementioned issues, I am now capable of migrating the tables. However, I am sometimes getting the following stacktrace as a warning which then forces the job to end. Before actually failing, the job repeats itself (don't know if this is default behaviour or not). Also, it seems like it either cannot write so many rows to the destination database or the connection is lost. This is holding me back from migrating specific tables. Any idea as to why?

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed. at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1246) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1241) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4564) at io.cdap.plugin.db.batch.sink.ETLDBOutputFormat$1.close(ETLDBOutputFormat.java:90) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:670) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:2021) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:797) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.distributed.MapReduceContainerLauncher.launch(MapReduceContainerLauncher.java:114) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second error, you are encountering a classloading bug: https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15636

For a workaround to this, please try to use the generic Database source and sink instead of the product specific databases. The configurations should be mostly the same.

Comment: Thanks again Edwin.
I will do as you suggested and will comeback to this with the results.

Comment: Edwin, I just wanted to say thank you.
I have now tried with generic sources and sinks as you suggested and everything works fine.
I will come back with more questions should any arise.
Thanks!

Comment: Glad things worked! Can you mark this question as completed?

Comment: One more thing Edwin. I have noticed that, when migrating relatively large tables (>100k rows), I get the third stacktrace I present in my question. This relates to a warn which then forces the job to end. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: How long is the job running for? I believe MySQL has a default timeout for connections. You should be able to modify your MySQL database to change the wait_timeout value

Comment: Hmm that might be it. It does run for a long period, more than several minutes. I will try to do that and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Edwin.
So, maximizing the wait_timeout value fixed the issue of the job being terminated. However, now it ran, repeated the job 4 times (at least it got 4x the actual number of rows in the table) and then failed with "MapReduce JobId job_1563316040868_0001 failed". Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will need to see the logs associated with that. Can you open a separate question for that? just to keep this question thread focus on one problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using version 1.2.0 of the SQL Server Database plugin from Hub?

Are you specifying the Import Query in the SQL Server properties? If not, please try specify the Import Query:

```
SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE $CONDITION
```

*note: only specify the `WHERE $CONDITION` if the number of splits to generate is greater than 1.*

Comment: Edwin, thank you for your answer.
The problem was indeed related to not having a specific import query, which I now added thus solving that problem.
However, I am now dealing with another problem. The stacktrace "io.cdap.plugin.db.DBRecord cannot be cast to io.cdap.plugin.db.DBRecord".
Any idea on how I can solve this?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have included it in the question. Thanks.