# How to fix "java.lang.NullPointerException: null" when doing MSSQL to BigQuery in Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm working on a Cloud Data Fusion POC, and I'm attempting to create a MSSQL to BigQuery pipeline. The connection works due to the fact that I'm able to import my schema from a query, however, I'm getting a `MapReduce Program "phase-1" failed` with a `java.lang.NullPointerException: null exception`

I've already attempted to use the generic database source and sink,as stated in this question [Getting Null Pointer Exception when mapping SQL Server Database to MySQL Database with MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56986123/getting-null-pointer-exception-when-mapping-sql-server-database-to-mysql-databas) The import query is also already specified.

Here's the full stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists$TransformingSequentialList.<init>(Lists.java:569) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.transform(Lists.java:553) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.FieldList.fromPb(FieldList.java:116) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Schema.fromPb(Schema.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableDefinition$Builder.table(TableDefinition.java:120) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.StandardTableDefinition.fromPb(StandardTableDefinition.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableDefinition.fromPb(TableDefinition.java:155) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableInfo$BuilderImpl.<init>(TableInfo.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Table.fromPb(Table.java:603) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getTable(BigQueryImpl.java:415) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.util.BigQueryUtil.getBigQueryTable(BigQueryUtil.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.validateSchema(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:291) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.initOutput(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:119) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.BigQuerySink.prepareRunInternal(BigQuerySink.java:80) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.prepareRun(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:88) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.prepareRun(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:57) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSink.lambda$prepareRun$0(WrappedBatchSink.java:52) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.Caller$1.call(Caller.java:30) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.StageLoggingCaller.call(StageLoggingCaller.java:40) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSink.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSink.java:51) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSink.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSink.java:37) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.submit.SubmitterPlugin.lambda$prepareRun$2(SubmitterPlugin.java:71) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext$2.run(AbstractContext.java:551) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.data2.transaction.Transactions$CacheBasedTransactional.finishExecute(Transactions.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.data2.transaction.Transactions$CacheBasedTransactional.execute(Transactions.java:211) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:546) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:534) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.submit.SubmitterPlugin.prepareRun(SubmitterPlugin.java:69) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.PipelinePhasePreparer.prepare(PipelinePhasePreparer.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.mapreduce.MapReducePreparer.prepare(MapReducePreparer.java:97) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.etl.batch.mapreduce.ETLMapReduce.initialize(ETLMapReduce.java:192) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.api.mapreduce.AbstractMapReduce.initialize(AbstractMapReduce.java:109) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.api.mapreduce.AbstractMapReduce.initialize(AbstractMapReduce.java:32) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService$1.initialize(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService$1.initialize(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.lambda$initializeProgram$1(AbstractContext.java:640) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:600) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.initializeProgram(AbstractContext.java:637) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService.beforeSubmit(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:547) ~[na:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService.startUp(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:226) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$1.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:47) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService$2$1.run(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:450) [na:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try deleting the target dataset and letting the pipeline auto create it? I suspect the pipeline is trying to write to a dataset with no fields.